# Ajax result change Jade assignment variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, pug

Looking to change a Jade assigned variable with the results of an ajax post so that the page's Jade loop utilizes the new data (updating only the parts of the dom that relate to the loop and not rendering the page over).

**route.js**

```
router.post('/initial', function(req, res) {
  res.render('/page', {data: data})
})
router.post('/refresh', function(req, res) {
  res.send(newdata)
})
```

**index.jade**

```
block content
  - var fluxdata = data
  each item in fluxdata
    span= item
  div#button
```

**client.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
  $.post('/refresh', function(newdata) {
    var fluxdata = newdata
  })
}
```

I tried out partials, but wasn't sure I was on the right track.  Looked around the internet and stackoverflow for a while and can't find a similar question about Jade assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Jade template
block content
    div(class="content")
        - var fluxdata = data
        each item in fluxdata
            span #{item.id} : #{item.username}
    div
        button(id="add") POST Data

after your template is rendered your html will look like this


// HTML rendered
<div class="content">
    <span>1 : Yves</span>
    <span>2 : Jason</span>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="add">POST DATA</button>
</div>

// backend code

var users = [
    {
        username: "Yves", 
        id: 1
    }, 
    {
        username: "Jason", 
        id: 2
    }
]

router.get("/initial", function(request, responser) {
    response.render("index", { data: users})
})


router.post("/refresh", function(request, responser) {
    users.push({username: "Alex",id: 1})

    response.json({ data: users})
})



// Your jquery code

$("#button").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    $.post('/refesh', function(data) {
        $(".content").html("")
        for(var user in data) {
            var span = $("<span>")          
            span.text(user.id + ": " + user.username )
            $(".content").append(span)
        }

    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in your  get "/initial" route handler, your are rendering the 


res.render("/page", {data : data })

before the template name you musn't put the / and the template in witch you are trying to use data that at push to the view  is index.jade


router.post('/initial', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {data: data})
})
```

Comment: yvesdaxmaz, thanks for pointing this out.  I chopped up my app to make the question simpler and you are correct that I would need to render index without a /.  Your response does not answer the question though.  Do you have any suggestions on how to properly change the Jade variable assignment?

Comment: when you send your ajax request, the template is rendered in that time you you haven't a jade template, a have a simple html page. and you can not replace the assisgn the result of your ajax to your template. you must write your javascript in the way that you manipulate the result and add some markup to your dom.

Comment: and the url to which the request is sent must return data, not a template like you did in your code. return some thing like json

Comment: Thanks for all the guidance yvesdaxmaz.  I'll write the logic to update parts of the dom directly in javascript after the initial page load.  I just accepted your answer with sample code above.  Thanks again!

Comment: it was a pleasure for me to help you.